# enchant.errors.DictNotFoundError: Dictionary for language 'en_US' could not be found

Tags: windows, dictionary, pyenchant, enchant

I started creating a word game for fun but I ran into an error after finishing the game with the enchant library having errors. Every time I click enter it says en_US could not be found.

enchant.errors.DictNotFoundError: Dictionary for language 'en_US' could not be found

I pip installed pyenchant and I already uninstalled and reinstalled it as well.(I am using windows by the way)

Comment: Any solutions yet? I'm facing the same error